# Schlage - latch stopped Retracting

Tags: latches

Suddenly the latch won’t retract unless I turn the knob. I have the Schlage Encode; I reached out because I was told it was faulty mechanism. They disagreed that my issue is related to the Encode yet I fell like I’ve read that this can be related. Should I push back? Other ideas? Thanks

Comment: When you input your code do you hear a mechanical sound like the latch is trying to open?

Comment: Please revise to describe the situation better.  I glean from your comments below that you're referring to when the door is _open_. How does the deadbolt get extended when the door's open to begin with?

Comment: It’s the latch not the deadbolt as stated

Answer (score 1):

Replace the batteries.  They may have enough juice to make the lock look operational, but not enough juice to actually move the deadbolt.

Comment: Agreed.   Do the simple things first.  Oh, and use Lithium batteries here.